# How to add a configurable product to cart (by child id and quantity)?

Tags: cart, configurable-product

I have the quantity and the id of a child product. Now I want to add it to the cart. But I get always the exception "Sale was closed for this product.". - Makes sense because the child product isn't visible individually.

But how can I add this product (or the parent with the right attributes) to the cart?

I tried to customize [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952580/add-multiple-products-to-cart-in-magento-1-7-0-2) but had no success.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right:

```
$params = array(
    'product'            => $_super_product_id,
    'qty'                => 1,
    'super_attribute'    => array($_id_of_the_attribute => $_option_id)
);
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->addProduct($_super_product_id, $params);
```

Comment: Tried this with an override of the cart-controller and it didn't work: When I click on the "add to cart"-button, the site reloads I get the "Please specify the product options" notice. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: $_super_product_id is the ID (int) or the code? We are trying to use the above to generate an addtocarturl that does not add the child dirctly - but rather the parent with the right childoption